# R plot date data multiple geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom

Plotting the below data. trying to include the lines per tech, Without using the facetwrap.
Plot both tech and files per enm --

| Date | emmm | task | coll_task | tech | filescount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | vnmenm1 | tr | e3g_tr_vnmenm1 | 3g | 1136 |
| 2023-06-01 | vnmenm1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmenm1 | 4g | 3475 |
| 2023-06-01 | vnmsgsn1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1 | 4g | 317 |
| 2023-06-03 | vnmenm1 | tr | e3g_tr_vnmenm1 | 3g | 1136 |
| 2023-06-03 | vnmenm1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmenm1 | 4g | 8899 |
| 2023-06-03 | vnmsgsn1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1 | 4g | 296 |
| 2023-06-04 | vnmenm1 | tr | e3g_tr_vnmenm1 | 3g | 1136 |
| 2023-06-04 | vnmenm1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmenm1 | 4g | 9034 |
| 2023-06-04 | vnmsgsn1 | tr | e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1 | 4g | 292 |

Using below code -

```
data %>% group_by(Date, emmm, tech, filescount) %>%  summarize(filescount = sum(filescount)) %>% ggplot(aes(Date, emmm, tech, color = filescount)) + geom_point(size = 2.4, alpha = 0.5) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = emmm), size = 1,  alpha = 0.4, stat = "identity", na.rm = TRUE)
```

gives an image like -
[image]

Any way to present with both tech and showing the filescount, i.e - geom_line per tech and filescount !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Your given test data as a dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    Date = as.Date(c("2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-03", "2023-06-03", "2023-06-03", "2023-06-04", "2023-06-04", "2023-06-04")),
    emmm = c("vnmenm1", "vnmenm1", "vnmsgsn1", "vnmenm1", "vnmenm1", "vnmsgsn1", "vnmenm1", "vnmenm1", "vnmsgsn1"),
    task = rep("tr", 9),
    coll_task = c("e3g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1", "e3g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1", "e3g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmenm1", "e4g_tr_vnmsgsn1"),
    tech = c("3g", "4g", "4g", "3g", "4g", "4g", "3g", "4g", "4g"),
    filescount = c(1136, 3475, 317, 1136, 8899, 296, 1136, 9034, 292)
)

# Create a dataframe to plot
df_sum <- df %>%
    group_by(emmm, tech, Date) %>%
    summarize(total_files = sum(filescount), .groups = 'drop')

# Plot the data
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = Date, y = total_files, group = interaction(emmm, tech), color = interaction(emmm, tech), linetype = interaction(emmm, tech))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = "Date", y = "Files per Tech", color = "Tech", linetype = "Tech") +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Emmm - Tech", labels = c("vnmenm1 - 3g", "vnmenm1 - 4g", "vnmsgsn1 - 4g")) +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Emmm - Tech", labels = c("vnmenm1 - 3g", "vnmenm1 - 4g", "vnmsgsn1 - 4g")) +
    theme_minimal()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the requirement to plot per emmm --- then per tech and filecount

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but I changed my answer. Let me know if this is what you mean.

Comment: amazing, this is what i meant, scale_color_discrete and scale_linetype_discrete are hardcoded, checking to put it automate as those emmm name always changes.

Comment: added auto labels --

apply(unique(df_sum[c("enm", "tech")]), 1, function(x) paste(paste(x[1], x[2] , sep='-')))

Comment: the blank date space in Jun02, any way it can be removed.

Comment: You could use 'scale_x_date(labels = function(x) format(x, "%b%d")) +' in your plot to format your date without a space (or however you want to format the date).